# Freeciv - Whole Stack Destroyed by Single Attack

Tags: freeciv

I find that in Freeciv, when you attack a whole stack of units (irrespective of how large this stack is), if your attacking unit is able to take out one of the strongest units in the stack, the entire stack gets destroyed. I don't understand how this is explained by anything in the [CombatRules](http://freeciv.wikia.com/wiki/Combat).

Haven't other people encountered this problem/anomaly? Is this a bug or feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the wiki page you linked, under Cities and Forts:

> When several units on the same square are attacked, the unit most capable of defense protects the entire square. If the defenders are within a city or fortress, the loss of that defender leaves the other units intact; but outside of such fortification, loss of the defender results in the loss of every unit in the square.

This works the same as I remember from the original Civ game, So I'd say this is definitely a feature.

Comment: That sounds like a rather unrealistic "feature"