# Is it possible to modify the ruleset so as to change stack destruction?

Tags: freeciv

This is actually a follow up to a [previous question of mine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93872/freeciv-whole-stack-destroyed-by-single-attack). It deals with the feature of the combat rules that destroys an entire stack of units (no matter how large) by a single unit as long as the single unit can kill the strongest unit in the stack. Why is this unrealistic? Well, because its unrealistic for a stack of 20 horsemen getting slaughtered by a single catapult. Or a fleet full of non-veteran battleships getting destroyed by a single veteran battleship. As much as some players hate stacking, this is just a deal breaker for me. Other methods to prevent stacking would be to inflict a little collateral damage on the stacked units like Civ 4 does.

So here is my question: Is it possible to incorporate such a change by modifying the ruleset file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are launching your own game of Freeciv you can play without stack destruction. When you set up the game you can pick your preferred Ruleset Version, and the select More Game Options.
[image: http://i.imgur.com/yPFITpi.png]

In the Game Settings window navigate to the military tab and **deselect** the rule **Do all units in tile die with defender**. Just click apply and you are good to go.

[image]